# Android Studio, emulator process was kiled

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have a problem with AVD in Android Studio, when i click to boot my device, warning appears that says emulator process was killed. **Is it possible that i have low RAM???**, I have 4GB.

Comment: I am having the same issue with API 30 system images.

Answer (score 0):

4GB RAM is good enough to run emulators. Go to AVD Manager. right click on your emulator configuration and do a "Wipe Data" . That should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried wiping data now, and it stil doesn't work. Also i created variable in system, everything is newest version, but its still killed